# Let $q_{1},q_{2},...$ be an indexing of the rational numbers in $(0,1)$. $f(x): (0,1) \rightarrow (0,1)$ by $f(x)=\sum_{j:q_{j}<x}2^{-j}$.

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Let $q_{1},q_{2},...$ be an indexing of the ration numbers in $(0,1)$. $f(x): (0,1) \rightarrow (0,1)$ by $f(x)=\sum_{j:q_{j}<x}2^{-j}$.

a. Show that f is discontinuous at every rational number in $(0,1)$.
b. Show that f is continuous at every irrational number in $(0,1).

Can anyone suggest me some hint of this question?

Comment: Consider left continuity and right continuity at a point